# change checkbox border color

Tags: jquery, css, border

can i change border color of checkbox by use css or jquery. i want change only border color of check box.

Comment: Are images an option? Otherwise you can't do this in a cross-browser consistent way.

Comment: most thanks for patrick. your tips was most useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to do this with pure css, you won't get an result that works in all browsers. if you use jqueryUI there are some implementations of checkboxes like [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ui-checkbox) or [this](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/checkbox-radiobutton/). otherwise you'll have to do something similar by yourself using images.

*edit:*
**please note:** as of today (march 2015) this post is about 5 years old - back then, the IE6 still had a market share of about 10% and even the newest IE (Version 8 at that time) was crappy as hell.
**This answer is technically outdated nowadays**.

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes are notorious for behaving differently to styles for each browser that renders them. As Nick Craver commented, images are the only reliable way to style checkboxes safely.